# Is it possible to use RSS feeds with Outlook 2003?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, rss, microsoft-outlook-2003

Is it possible to use [RSS feeds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSS) with Outlook 2003 (Microsoft Office Outlook 2003 [11.8217.8221] SP3)?

If it is possible, what are the actual steps to add an RSS feed, say `http://herdingcode.com/?feed=rss2`?

This is in an office environment partly under [Citrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Citrix_Systems#Products) (I am not sure exactly what it is, but some applications, including Outlook, are started from an Internet Explorer window titled "MetaFrame Presentation Server") so it may or may not be possible to add extra "things" to Outlook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No Outlook 2003 does not have any built-in RSS reader support.

It is very unlikely that you will have the ability to install any Outlook plugins in a terminal server environment.